# SPARQL: select the count of something but also show all the instances

Tags: sparql

I have a dataset that I will describe in a general way.
Entities of type A consist of entities B.

How would I write a query that prints a table with the following columns:
entity A | number of Bs that belong to A | a B entity that belongs to A.

So basically I want to return all the Bs that belong to A and in the second column also have the total number of Bs that belong to A.

Comment: `select ?a (COUNT(DISTINCT ?b) as ?b_cnt) (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?b ; separator=", ") as ?b_list)  where { ... } group by ?a`

Comment: I don't want the Bs to be in one column separated by commas. I want to have the total number of Bs repeated every time in the second column and some B in the third.

Comment: For all Bs that belong to one A

Comment: last time that I'll answer here: `select ?a ?b_cnt ?b where { ...  {select ?a (COUNT(DISTINCT ?b) as ?b_cnt) where { ... } group by ?a } }` - if it should be done for a specific ?a, use VALUES ?a {the_uri_of_the_a} inside the query